# Incandescent to LED change

Tags: lighting

There are 3 incandescent recessed light fixtures in my kitchen. I purchased the Home Depot ecosmart LED bulbs 65W. One of the recessed fixtures will only work with the incandescent lightbulb.  I have tried the new LED bulbs in other light fixtures, therefore the bulbs are tested good.  Looking for options to why the fixture will not support the LED bulb? the three fixtures work off the same 3-way switch (2 actual switches}.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is either switch a dimmer?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that the center contact in the one fixture is a bit lower than the others and not making contact with the bulb. The incandescent may have a slightly longer reach than the LED. Whether or not you can fix this depends on the tools you have at your disposal, if the switch is correctly wired on the hot side of the circuit, and your confidence level working with electricity.

Comment: Some LEDs say 'dimmable' on the packaging, but I think this is with a certain new type of dimmer switch.  Some old dimmer switches will not light up some LEDs. If there are multiple lights on the same dimmer switch, it *may be* that putting one incandescent light on the dimmer in parallel with the LED will allow the LED to function.

Answer (score 2):

I have experienced problems with the bulbs not screwing all the way in, usually due to the shape of the LED bulb not being quite the same as an incandescent bulb, and at least once from malformed threads.

Since your bulb works in other fixtures, I'd bet on the one fixture having something that the LED bulbs are sticking on before they get all the way in, or that the center contact has been flattened by some previous bulb and needs (with the circuit breaker for this circuit off, please) to be gently bent/pulled up; or in case of severe damage, replace the socket, or the fixture.